# Pointwise limit of a measurable function is still measurable, for weak star convergence measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose I have a sequence of functions $(f_n(x))$: $\mathbb R^N\to\mathbb R^M$ such that $|f_n(x)|=1$ a.e. $x\in \mu_n$ where $\mu_n$ is a finite Radon measure over $\mathbb R^N$, and $f_n(x)$ is $\mu_n$ measurable.

Assume $\mu_n\to\mu$ in weak star sense. Also, define $f(x):=\lim f_n(x)$ whenever a limit exists.

My question: do I have $|f(x)|=1$ a.e. $x\in\mu$ and $f(x)$ is $\mu$ measureable? and, do I have $\lim f_n(x)=f(x)$ point-wise a.e. $\mu$? (of course up to a subsequence)

---

My try:

Let $S_n:=\{x\in\mathbb R^N, |f_n(x)|\neq 1\}$ and $S:=\bigcup S_n$. Then clearly for each $x\in S^c$, we can define $f^j(x):=\lim f^j_n(x)$, maybe via a subsequence, but the limit will exists. Here by $f^j_n(x)$ we mean the $j$-th component of $f_n(x)$. Of course, in this way we have $|f(x)|=1$ for $x\notin S$.

Then, as long as I can prove $S$ is a null set of $\mu$ I am done. But I got stuck here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this isn't true. You can have a set S which is null for every $\mu_n$ but not null for $\mu$.

For example, let $\mu_n$ be the uniform probability measure on a ball of radius $1/n$ centered at the origin. Then $\{0\}$ is $\mu_n$-null for every $n$, but the weak-star limit is a point mass at 0.

This should also help you write down a counterexample to your original claim.

Comment: hmm... dead end again! Thanks for your answer!