# The pointwise limit of a measurable function is still measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

This is a previous [discussion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1404180/pointwise-limit-of-a-measurable-function-is-still-measurable-for-weak-star-conv) but I just found I didn't get the answer I want...

The question is as follows: Assume a sequence of Radon measure $\mu_n\to\mu$ in weak star sense. The domain of $\mu$ and $\mu_n$ is the standard lebesgue measurable set over $\mathbb R^N$. And a sequence of $\mu_n$ measurable function $f_n\to f$ pointwise. (i.e., for each $n$, $f_n$ is $\mu_n$ measurable).

My question: Can we show that $f$ is $\mu$ measurable?

Thank you!

Comment: The question is not clear.  Are $\mu_n$ and $\mu$ supposed to be measures?  Usually one speaks of a function being measurable with respect to a sigma-algebra, not with respect to a measure.  The domain of a measure is a sigma-algebra.  Do $\mu$ and all of $\mu_n$ have the same sigma-algebra as their domain?  If so the question should be whether the measurability of all terms in a sequence of functions entails the measurability of their pointwise limit, and there's no sequence of measures involve; just one sigma-algebra. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy but when you see a function is $\mu$ measurable or not, you do need to concern the measure itself right? You have to determine whether the inverse of the function is a measurable set. But you are right, I update my post with the information of underlining sigma-algebra.

Comment: One of the vaunted advantages of Lebesgue's theory over Riemann's is supposed to be the fact that in Lebesgue's theory a sequence of that can be integrated functions cannot converge pointwise to a function that cannot be integrated.  I don't recall the details of the proof, but (1) a measurable function is one under which inverse-images of measurable sets are measurable, and (2) the set of measurable sets is closed under complementation and under countable unions and countable intersections. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: $\ldots\,{}$but nonetheless a sequence of integrable functions can converge to a non-integrable function, since "integrable" is defined as meaning the integral of the absolute value is finite. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me answer a precise form of your question with an example. Let the $\mu_n$ and $\mu$ be probability measures on the Borel subsets ${\mathcal B}$ of the interval $(0,1]$.  A function $f_n:(0,1]\to{\Bbb R}$ is then $\mu_n$-measurable provided there is a Borel function $g_n:(0,1]\to{\Bbb R}$ such that $A:=\{x\in(0,1]:f_n(x)\not=g_n(x)\}$ is an element of the $\mu_n$-completion of ${\mathcal B}$ and $\mu_n(A)=0$.

Now let's take $\mu_n$ to be the (discrete) uniform distribution on $D_n=\{k\cdot 2^{-n}:k=1,2,\ldots,2^n\}$.  Then $\mu_n$-measurability is a rather weak property: each function mapping $(0,1]$ to ${\Bbb R}$ is $\mu_n$-measurable. Evidently $\mu_n\to\mu$ (weak-star) where $\mu$ is Lebesgue measure on $(0,1]$.
Let $E$ be a non-Lebesgue-measurable subset of $(0,1]$, and let $f_n=f=1_E$ for each $n$, where $1_E$ is the indicator function for $N$.  Each $f_n$ is $\mu_n$-measurable, $f_n\to f$ pointwise, but $f$ is not $\mu$-measurable.